# How do I use synchronization primitives to help Waiters service Tables in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have 3 classes. A Waiter (thread), a Table (thread), and a Queue (not a thread) (simiple first in first out queue).

Initially a couple of waiters are created and then tables are created. There are many more tables than waiters so tables have to "wait" for waiters to serve them. I am supposed to use "java synchronization primitives, wait notify, and notifall" to solve this problem. Here are the guidelines for each class:

Table:
When it is started, it enters the queue and then calls an internal method waitService() which returns if it has been serviced or waits for a waiter.

the way I have this method right now:

```
$if(serviced)
        return 0;
    try {
        this.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Waiter:
The waiter code is not really giving me any issues but essentially the way it works is that in the run method there is an infinite loop that checks if there is a table waiting and then gives that table service for a random amount of time after which it checks if another table is waiting. It lets the table know it is giving it service by calling giveService() method inside the table class.

Queue:
It has a list of waiters and a list of tables. The waiter calls nextTable() in the queue class when it is ready to give service. this is how I have it set up:

```
$public Table nextTable(Waiter w) throws InterruptedException {

    if(closed)
        return null;
    if(tables.isEmpty()) {
        w.wait();
    }
    Table t =  tables.removeFirst();
    t.notify();
    return t;   
}
```

I know the above may have some very fundamental mistakes but essentially I have no clue how synchronization primitives work in java. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this homework?  It should be marked as such.

Comment: yea it is but I didn't know a way to ask this question without mentioning the actual hw. I don't want anybody to solve it for me, just someone who can explain how to use synchronization in java.

Comment: No problem.  I was just pointing out that it should have the homework tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as good of a tutorial as any on using wait(), notify() and notifyAll(). Read through it first, and see if you have additional questions that either SO hasn't already answered, or something in particular to your problem.

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=306

Comment: the thing is none of my methods (as defined by the hw) are synchronized in the definition. i.e the way they are given to me is public void giveService() and public void nextTable() throws InterruptedException;

Comment: Using method synchronized is essentially short-hand for a synchronized block with the object instance as the lock. You can use a synchronized block inside your method, which prevents multiple threads from accessing your block at the same time. Otherwise they'd all sit at wait(), and notify() will randomly select one of the waiting threads, not the only thread sitting at wait().

Comment: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_producer_consumer.shtml  Here, the lock is on the List. The first entering thread will add lines to the list, and wake the logging thread sitting at wait(). If a second thread attempts to call log() at the same time, it sits at the synchronized block so it can't write to the list can call notify() as well. It's a simplistic example, but should illuminate the synchronized block question.